# Why npycharm telling me format is not an attribute of string

Tags: python, pycharm

This is the code I'm trying to run

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input():
line = line.strip() 
keys = line.split()  
for key in keys:     
    value = 1
    print '{0}\t{1}'.format(key, value)
```

This is with pycharm 5.0.4 and Python 2.7.8. And pycharm keeps bombing out and not printing my output but instead printing the error:

```
print '{0}\t{1}'.format(key, value)  #the {} is replaced by 0th,1st items in
format list
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'format'
```

This makes no sense to me.  It runs fine from the linux command prompt (using Python 2.6.6)

Comment: Maybe you're running Python < 2.5? Check your Python version in Pycharm again.

Comment: Run `import sys;print(sys.version)`.

Comment: Did that and got this                                                                             :Python 2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:08:48) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>>> import sys;print(sys.version)
2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:08:48) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I changed File-Settings-Project to point to 2.7 but the actual file was still pointing to 2.4.4. I changed that to 2.7 and now I'm not getting the error anymore